# LINQ and Boolean Values

Tags: c#, linq

I have a **LINQ** Query which returns a Boolean.

```
     Boolean status=true;
     var s = from p in msg where p.Type == false select false;
```

im required to set status from the value from the LINQ query which is a **boolean** how to take a approach to this

**If the LINQ query has a single `false` i need to return a false as Boolean thats what i need**

Comment: No, it returns a possibly empty list of booleans. What is the question?

Comment: You might be better of explaining what you are trying to do.

Comment: You cant. Linq to object queries return IEnumerable<T> of objects.

Comment: @Sudantha: So if the Linq returns more than one false do you want to return true?

Comment: If LINQ has one `false` i need to return a Boolean `False`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

At the moment assumign p has lots of msgs then s is going to be an enumerable with zero to lots of falses in. You might want to consider a different operator like

```
!msg.Any(x=>x.Type=false)
```

Or better thanks to Ray in comments:

```
msg.All(x => x.Type)
```

Any returns true if the condition is satisfied by anything in p. All returns true if the condition is satisfied in all of them (and will thus immediately return if it finds one that doesn't match).

Alternatively with your code you could just do:

```
status = s.Count()==0;
```

If your s is empty (no falses in it) then it will return true, if it has one or more falses it will return false.

Comment: `p.All(x => x.Type)` would be equivalent to your statement (assuming Type is boolean).

Comment: @Ray: possibly, but presumably `All` needs to iterate through the whole array whereas `Any` will stop after finding the first valid value. May not be a big thing but if x has a gazillion elements it could be a big difference. :)

Comment: @Chris: All will stop the first time it fonds a non-match. It's the logical opposite of Any.

Comment: Chris, I wouldn't assume All goes over the whole array. Given `{ false, false, true }` I only need to look at the first element to know they're not all true.

Comment: @Ray: D'oh! My bad. Yes, you're right. I was having a moment. I will update with your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

So far as I understand the question, this all depends on what the purpose of your `status` flag is. Since the LINQ query will return an enumerable collection of `boolean` values, you will need to determine what the `status` flag should be assigned to based on this collection.

In this case, you will end up with an arbitrarily sized collection of `false` values. So if you wish `status` to be `true` if you have no `false` values, you simply need to query the size of the collection. i.e.:

```
status = s.Count() == 0;  // Note: This is an example using the System.Linq namespace
```

Comment: If the LINQ query has a single `false` i need to return a false value thats what i need

Comment: In that case, simply use: `bool status = !p.Any(element => !element.Type);`

Comment: @Slade: this is complicated by the fact Sudantha says he needs a *single* false... This may or may not mean one or more falses.