# The most efficient way to check records in a database exist, using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am using Linq and to check whether or not a record exists in the database and that it is the latest version. I can do this using Linq

```
bool query = db.foo.Any(x => x.Id == list.Id);
```

And then checking to see if this produced a true or false result.

The issue I have with this approach is that if I want to check all the attributes of the table to determine if the existing data differs from the new copy then it requires me to specify a mapping for each attribute and list item.

Is there a way I can iterate through or are there other alternatives available?

`x` refers to the Entity framework object that is representing the DB
`list` is a list that is mapped 1 to 1 to the Entity Framework object.

Comment: Using `All` will check whether *all* records have the given ID. I suspect you want `Any` instead. As for the rest of your question: that's normally one reason to have some sort of "last update timestamp" or version column.

Comment: Okay cool thanks. That is what I was originally using until I came across this answer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8518391/3056507) and misinterpreted what he was explaining. As for the database field unfortunately I have no control over that hence why I am trying to find an alternative solution.

Comment: Would an Extension Method be sufficient? If so look into that.

Comment: @Corey,Also, you can use reflection facilities to check properties easily to prevent mapping each attributes

Answer (score 0):

```
foo query = db.foo.Where(x => x.Id == list.Id).FirstOrDefault();

if(query != null)
{
    properties = query.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach(PropertyInfo prop in properties)
    {
        if (list.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name) != null)
        {
            var val1 = list.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(list);
            var val2 = prop.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).GetValue(prop);
            // do your checking here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a sort of `for each` loop to iterate over all the columns for a row, and check that they match the corresponding data from the list - is that correct?

The short answer is: Sorry, I don't think you can do that (at least not without using some reflection tricks, which might be rather messy, and will not perform as well as you probably want).

With SQL you can write: `SELECT * FROM table (...)`, but there is no such option in Linq; you need to specify the names of each column explicitly.

What you could and probably should do instead, is what Jon Skeet mentioned briefly in a comment: Add a version number, or possibly a timestamp that you can check. Write your logic in such a way that you can be certain that if the version is correct/updated, then the row is valid.

You can then check the validity of a specific row by looking at it's version number. You could for instance do something like this:

```
// Does a row with specified ID exist and the newest version exist:
bool isRowValid = db.foo.Any(x => x.Id == list.Id && 
                                  x.VersionNr == list.newestVersionNr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool chechExists = db.foo.Exists(x => x.Id == list.Id);
```

This will return bool as you wanted